# Server Authentication require in Cygwin64

Tags: cygwin

When i try to download package from cygwin i'm getting problem please check below image.But it works before couple of hours.

[image]

Help me to resolve ....

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It seems you have a Proxy in the middle

Comment: Ohhhh..Thank you i will check my proxy Settings....